# How to design a frozen left navigation column for vertical scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, html

as in Google news or [pulsme](http://www.pulse.me/) land pages.
  Obviously, the main advantage of this being when user scrolls down in the main document, the navigation-menu is still remains visible the screen.
  I tried `position:fixed`for the `<td>` element. But the problem is that when the page is viewed on a mobile device (small screen) the text mixes with the main content. I am okay with the solution which is *not table* but preferably should not use any external libraries. I also tried `<iframe>`... but could not get it running. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the relevant code for us to review?

Comment: Don't mix tables and `fixed`. Just make it a `div` or `nav`. Also, with small-screen media, you will probably want to do something different. Extremely hard to say anything without code and more specific description of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to add a menu in a div and the content in another

```
<div id="menu">Some Menu Options</div>
<div id="cont">Your Content</div>
```

Then in CSS

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
```

Off course you could replace `150px` with any other value.

Comment: position:relative with top margin equal top menu height is much better approach

Comment: You could do that to, I've never had problems with this approach.

Comment: Many users change the font size of your page by configuring their browser settings. If you use absolute positioning, things will not align right for them.

In absolute positioning, when your page gets more complex, a single design decision would require you to reposition all of the elements, but in relative positioning, you would only need to change one value, and all the other elements would adjust accordingly.

Comment: Never tought of it like that. THNX for your information

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
 $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        $el = $('nav');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
            $('nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-10px', 'left':'150px', 'right':'0'});
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 80 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
            $('nav').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '63px', 'left':'', 'right':'' });
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/34uLcfwd/)

**CSS Only**

```
#cssmenu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/ohk802j8/)

Comment: completely unnecessary, it can be achieved with just css, no need to include jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

1) don't use tables. use div with class, e.g. wrapper for sticky navigation: `<div class="sticky-nav"></div>` 
2) set these rules (make adjustments for your design):

```
.sticky-nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div id="leftnav"> content </div>
```

css:

```
#leftnav{
  background: #111;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```